# Build matplots multiple plots of a dataframe with for loops

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame named train with differents columns named `sales`, `fuelcost` and `shippingtime`. I want to plot `sales` against different variables as `fuelcost`, `shippingtime`. How can this be done?

With seaborn this would be:

```py
pp = sns.pairplot(data=train, y_vars=['sales'], x_vars=['fuelcost', 'shippingtime'])
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm new, so sorry for this:   
labels = [fuelcost, shippingtime]
plt.scatter(data['sales'], data[labels])

Comment: Please do not use the comments to show what you've tried so far. Edit the question and ensure that this is readable for others. Make it comfortable for others to help you to get good answers.

Comment: Thank you!  @colidyre

Comment: Consider creating a function instead of for loops, that takes two columns as input. Then you just have to call the function for the different plots.